# Decrementing an array from last element in C

Tags: c

I want to decrement an array from last element in C. I first wrote the following code to increment an array from the first element:

```
#include<stdio.h>


    int x[11] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}; 
    int *pointer, count;
int main (void) {

    pointer = x;
    for (count = 0; count < 11; count++)
        printf("%d\n", *pointer++);
    return 0;
}
```

This works fine. But then I tried to decrement the elements by modifying the code to this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

    int x[11] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}; 
    int *pointer, count;
int main (void) {

    pointer = x[10];
    for (count = 0; count < 11; count++)
        printf("%d\n", *pointer--);
    return 0;
}
```

But of course I am doing something wrong. I'd appreciate it very much if you could help me to understand my mistake.

Comment: Use `pointer = x+10;` or `pointer = &x[10];`.

Comment: Pay attention to compiler diagnostic messages

Comment: note the Precedence of the operators, and the Associativity.  Your not lucky this time, both the *(dereference) and -- operators have the same precedence.  and the the associativity for those two operators is right to left.  However, to avoid future problems, write this kind of statement: printf("%d\n", *pointer--); as: rintf("%d\n", *pointer); pointer--;  otherwise the pointer is already decremented before accessing where the value where pointer points.  Similar considerations need to be applied to the statement: printf("%d\n", *pointer++);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pointer = x[10];` should be `pointer = &x[10];`.

You're setting `pointer` to the integer value `x[10]`. What you want to do is set `pointer` to the address of the last element in `x`.

Comment: Exactly, that is correct, I just changed it and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You have two options which are equivalent.

```
pointer = &x[10];
pointer = x + 10;
```

Either will achieve the effect of making the pointer point at the 10th element of x.